# Is there any way or gem to track successful social sharing the pages for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter

I have spend lot of time in R&D for the solutions but didn't get much success and not find an easy solution.

========

Here is what I want to do:

I am creating a rails application which have few pages. The pages are socially locked, Only logged-in user can unlock it by sharing the page on social website.

What I am planning:

I will update the things at my end if user successfully share page.

========

So basically I want to track the page was shared successfully or not via tokens or something like to give access to user on the page.

Please help me out on this. Any help really matters me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a gem that also draws the share buttons, or are you planning on doing that yourself?

Comment: Did any of your R&D produce code or prototypes that at least show what you are attempting? If so, please show some of it, because it is not very clear what you are trying to do or what your problem is.

Comment: I have tried sharethis and addthis widgets for sharing the pages, but didn't able to track is user share the page or cancel it.

I want to track the successful shares and perform the actions accordingly at my end

Answer (score 0):

You can look for things left behind by "Logins" or requests sent (ex. Ajax) while on the site but like the previous user mentioned. Do you have a more specific example of what you are attempting? I have a few gems in mind but also, you need to code most of it yourself.

If you want what I think, Have you taken a look at the gems such:
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'omniauth-identity'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
There's other gems that leave behind variables for you to use according to what actions are performed on these sites.

```
def auth_hash
  request.env['____var____']
end
```

`use OmniAuth::Builder`

### and use them like:

`provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET']`